# Unwanted top space in UIAlertController TextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode6, uialertcontroller

I am trying to create an dialog box to ask a file name to save.

Somehow the showed textfield has an extra space above and I cannot remove it. The space is not usable (it is not a line, just a top margin)

I couldn't get rid of it even by trying to change the .frame.height property of the textfield.

Please help! I don't understand why this is happening?

The ScreenShot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQYjz.png

The code is:

```
    var fieldSetListName: UITextField!

    func askForSetListName() {

    //Create the AlertController
    let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Name", message: "Enter a name for Setlist", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    //Create and add the Cancel action
    let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
        //Do some stuff
    }
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    //Create and an option action
    let okAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
    //Do some other stuff
    self.saveSetListAndDismiss(self.fieldSetListName.text)
    }

    alertController.addAction(okAction)
    //Add a text field
    alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { textField -> Void in
    textField.textColor = UIPalette.DarkText
    textField.placeholder = "(venue, festival, date etc.)"
    self.fieldSetListName = textField
    }

    //Present the AlertController
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

For anybody who comes across this kind of problem, setting rowHeight property of  UITableView globally using UIAppearance effects the textfield height inside the alertview:

I got rid of the line: UITableView.appearance().rowHeight = 50

Answer (score 0):

Add textField like this:

```
 var example :UITextField
 var inputText : String
 let exampletextField = actionSheetController.textFields![0] as UITextField
 exampletextField.textColor = UIPalette.DarkText
 exampletextField.placeholder = "(venue, festival, date etc.)"
 inputText = exampletextField.text
```